# Express - Get domain name server is running on

Tags: javascript, http, express, domain-name

Does ExpressJs provide a way to get the domain name the server is running on.

For example, if I run the server on a machine with IP address **xxx.xxx.x.x** witch translates to the domain name **www.mydomain.com**, does ExpressJs provide an easy way to get **www.mydomain.com**

My Thoughts

- Most likely not
- A DNS lookup is the way to do this
- It's just easier to hardcode the domain name in the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`req.hostname`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req)

Comment: Works as far as I can see.